# Firebase Crashlytics Missing Dsym Crash Reports with <Compiler generated> __hidden#587 when build an ipa

Tags: ios, firebase, crashlytics, xcode10, google-fabric

Integrated google firebasecrahlytics in my project.

I have noticed when running my application through the simulator and force a crash,  i am able to see the crash report correctly as in attached screen shot.

when i created an .ipa  with bitcode enabled and force a crash,  i am able to see the crash report with **Compiler generated** reports at line 0

when i created an .ipa keeping bitcode enabled  and upload dysm manually and force a crash  i am able to see the crash report with getting **__hidden#587** reports.

**How can i get the correct reports as of simulator.**

**please note my applications are not in the app store and I do not have itunes connect I am using an enterprise account.**

PFA screen shot
[image]

Comment: Did you get the solution? I am also facing similar issues

Comment: any luck? facing same issue